# \b python doesn't delete character

Tags: python, shell, python-3.x

So I go through a book, and copied the exact same code as in there. What the code should do, is that the \b deletes the line so the position gets updated always at the same place. In my case though it draws wierd blue cirlces. I tried it without flush= True but it gives same result.

```
while True:
    x,y  = pyautogui.position()
    posStr = 'X: '+ str(x).rjust(4)+ ' Y: ' +str(y).rjust(4)
    print ( posStr, end='')
    print('\b' *len(posStr), end='', flush= True)
```

How can I get that effect of having the output being updated?

edit:
to be more precise:
when i have the following code:

```
import pyautogui
while True:
    x,y  = pyautogui.position()
    posStr = 'X: '+ str(x).rjust(4)+ ' Y: ' +str(y).rjust(4)
    print ( posStr, end='')
    print('\b' *len(posStr), end='', flush= True)
```

i get that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhnqQ.png
I endless line with the wierd blue circles printed for \b (while it actually should delete a character)

when i use the code:

```
import pyautogui
while True:
    x,y  = pyautogui.position()
    posStr = 'X: '+ str(x).rjust(4)+ ' Y: ' +str(y).rjust(4)
    print ( '\r'+ posStr, end='')
```

I get the following result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdy6b.png
I endless line of text.
Somehow i just can't get it to delete already writen stuff with either of '\r' or '\b'.

So what is the problem?

Comment: `\b` tells the *shel or console* to go back a step. It depends on the exact shell or console if it'll also erase that character position. Most *do not*.

Comment: Generally speaking, `\r` followed by enough new text to cover the old is a more reliable way of 'clearing' a line, especially if you pad with spaces.

Comment: Also see [How to delete line with echo?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26576)

Comment: the problem is \b and \r dont work AT ALL. for the person \b works.

Answer (score 1):

```
while True:
    x, y = pyautogui.position()
    print('X: %4d   Y: %4d' % (x, y), end = '\r')
```

`\r` will cause the next print to write to the same. your string must have the same length or you can pad with spaces.

`\n` would start a newline `\r` do not.

Alternative solution:

```
while True:
    x, y = pyautogui.position()
    print('X: %d Y: %d' % (x, y) + ' ' * 20, end = '\r')
```

`+ ' ' * 20` will write 20 spaces to the screen to delete the rest of the line

using only `'X: %d Y: %d'` without padding (`%4d` or `+ ' ' * 20`)

```
# x, y = 1000, 1000 prints:
X: 1000 Y: 1000
# x, y = 30, 40 prints:
X: 30 Y: 401000
```

the zeroes will remain after the first print, and you will get dirty data.

Comment: I can't test it right now, but I think it'd be possible to add a `\r` at the beginning of the line instead of placing it at the end so you don't need to pad the string with spaces. You'd need to end the last line with `\n`, though.

Comment: tested before posted. if you start with `'\r'` you must end with `''` (nothing) `'\n'` will cause a newline and you cannot go up. padding is for clearing the actual content of the line

Comment: Read the second comment of @martijn-pieters, he is right.